# GCM Only Sends Message to Latest Registered Device in php

Tags: php, google-cloud-messaging

I have two devices registered with GCM. However, when testing sending a message from the server, it only sends a message to that latest registered device instead of all registered devices.

How can this be altered to send to those device ids:

```
<?php
    //generic php function to send GCM push notification
   function sendPushNotificationToGCM($registatoin_ids, $message) {
        //Google cloud messaging GCM-API url
        $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
        $fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
            'data' => $message,
        );
        // Google Cloud Messaging GCM API Key
        define("GOOGLE_API_KEY", "(API KEY)"); // My API Key form Google console
        $headers = array(
            'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);   
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);               
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
    }
?>
<?php

    //this block is to post message to GCM on-click
    $pushStatus = "";   
    if(!empty($_GET["push"])) { 
        $gcmRegID  = file_get_contents("GCMRegId.txt");
        $pushMessage = $_POST["message"];   
        if (isset($gcmRegID) && isset($pushMessage)) {      
            $gcmRegIds = array($gcmRegID);
            $message = array("message" => $pushMessage);    
            $pushStatus = sendPushNotificationToGCM($gcmRegIds, $message);
        }       
    }

    //this block is to receive the GCM regId from external (mobile apps)
    if(!empty($_GET["shareRegId"])) {
        $gcmRegID  = $_POST["regId"]; 
        file_put_contents("GCMRegId.txt",$gcmRegID);
        echo "Ok!";
        exit;
    }   
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) Server in PHP</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) Server in PHP</h1> 
        <form method="post" action="gcm.php/?push=1">                                                
            <div>                                
                <textarea rows="2" name="message" cols="23" placeholder="Message to transmit via GCM"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div><input type="submit"  value="Send Push Notification via GCM" /></div>
        </form>
        <p><h3><?php echo $pushStatus; ?></h3></p>        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's your question - how to store multiple device IDs or how to send the notifications to them? The `sendPushNotificationToGCM` function seems to handle this correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the new deviceId being stored is not clearing the original contents. I.e. the file operation while adding a new device id Should be of append mode. This might be causing the problem of sending only to the latest device.

Comment: Make a request to the API with the deviceID message. You need to store the deviceId on you own. Why else does the question have the php code with way to store deviceid??

Comment: Storing deviceId is not a API PROVIDED BY GOOGLE. Api is to send notification. So my answer to make sure that new entry does not wipe original data is valid.